# Get documents using conditional filter MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am performing translation on a site. It has following db structure with version **3.6**:

```
{
    _id: XXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "title": "hello",
    "description": "test 123",
    "language_code": "en" 
}
```

By default the site is loaded in english language, which works fine. But If change the language to suppose spanish:

- If no content is added for spanish then by default english content should be displayed for spanish
- If content is added for spanish (with language code es in the db) then it should show spanish language content.

I have tried following query:

```
db.sections.find({
    $expr: {
        $eq:[
            {$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$language_code", "es" ] }, "es", "en" ] },
            "$language_code" 
        ]
    }
})
```

But when the content is added for both en & es then it is returning data for both languages.

What is wrong with this query ? How can return content conditionally that if no content found for es then return en content else return es content ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the logic you are thinking should be changed. Any how the query will run whatever you select. So you can easily change the language based on the input https://mongoplayground.net/p/fBJgqrKJaZX and

Comment: Thanks @varman but did you read the whole requirement ? I have already tried this. In this case if document for es is not added then it will return empty result. But I need en data in that case.

Comment: The above query you mentioned gets all documents bcs all condition is getting satisfied. But it wont get other than es or en, eg : https://mongoplayground.net/p/hCaEJmINhMO . That's why I mention to get specific language input. For eg : `input=es`, then run the query i mentioned, if no any docs found, get the "en"

Comment: You mean I need to execute two queries ? first run with es; if no docs found then run for en ?